# Simple Server Sent Event is not streaming C#

Tags: c#, .net, server-sent-events

I am a beginner for server side events and implemented a simple server side event. But, there was no events in the browser event stream tab after I run the program. Check the below image for my event stream tab.

[image]

My C# code is as follows.

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("/sse")]
        public async Task SSE()
        {
            await HttpContext.SSEInitAsync();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            await HttpContext.SSESendDataAsync("test");
        }

    }
```

SSEHttpContextExtensions.cs

```
    public static class SSEHttpContextExtensions
    {

        public static async Task SSEInitAsync(this HttpContext ctx)
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
            await ctx.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }

        public static async Task SSESendDataAsync(this HttpContext ctx, string data)
        {
            foreach (var line in data.Split('\n'))
                await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("data: " + line + "\n");

            await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("\n");
            await ctx.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Why there is no record in the eventstream tab after I run the program?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You didn't post any SSE code, just code that writes to the response directly when a specific action is called using GET. That's still a GET response, not an SSE

Comment: If you want to send notifications to clients why not use SignalR and let *it* decide what mechanism to use? Alternatively, check [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/htmx-aspnetcore/server-sent-events/) which  shows how to use [Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents) to simplify sending events from a long running background service

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added SSE code in SSEHttpContextExtensions class with "eventstream" header and all that. Can you tell me what should I need to do make this SSE instead of GET?

Comment: You didn't. That's a plain old HTTP response. As the name says, a Server Sent Event is an event sent from the server, not a response to a client request. Perhaps you should read [SSE Support in ASP.NET Core](https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/02/server-sent-events-sse-support-for.html) which explains what SSEs are and how they work?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I followed this article. As he says it works. that is my doubt. https://itnext.io/server-side-event-streams-with-dotnet-core-and-typescript-d20c84017480

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I chose SSE over SignalR because I need only one way communication plus it happens over HTTP. Do not need to open web sockets in SSE as in SignalR.]

Comment: I will check your article posted in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any built-in support for server sent events on .NET 7?

Comment: There's not a lot of demand for built-in support and  [Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.AspNetCore.ServerSentEvents) seems to be enough for most. SSE is an old technology that needs care to scale well, is more expensive and more complex than WebSockets, and SignalR already simplifies using both. The [MDN page on SSEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) contains some strong warnings. People are more interested in built-n support of new protocols like gRPC and gRPC-web